# how to use built in cedet in emacs 23.3?

Tags: emacs, intellisense, cedet

I am using emacs 23.3

I heard that emacs 23.3 include cedet by default

but how can I use them? how should I change my ".emacs" file for ..

1. function parameter hint 
   (when I type "malloc("  then parameter hint arise somewhere)
2. auto complete menu
   (when there are variable "qwer", "qwert", and "qwerty" and when I type "qwe" then those 3 selectable hint arise somewhere)

when I edit c or cpp file?

(and.. any suggestion for cedet feature?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you asking as someone using an old CEDET distribution, or someone new to CEDET?  I'll assume the later.

First, you need to enable semantic with this in your `.emacs`:

```
(semantic-mode 1)
```

next, if your project is particularly large (more than 1 directory full of files) you will need to enable EDE.

```
(global-ede-mode 1)
```

and figure out what kind of project to use.  Your project might be auto-detected if it is one of the common ones, otherwise you should create one of type ede-cpp-root to just wrap that directory, or try enabling the generic project types that use a Makefile, scons or cmap, or with:

```
(ede-enable-generic-projects)
```

Generic projects can sometimes get in the way, so they are disabled by default.

You would then need to enable the idle summary mode:

```
(global-semantic-idle-summary-mode 1)
```

Look in the Development menu for other options.